# How do i clear text out of a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

Okay here is what i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var where = document.getElementById("info")
    var texts = false;
    function clear() {
        where.innerHTML = "";
    };

    function dostuff(what) {

            if(where.style.value === ""){
    var comm = document.createTextNode(what);
    where.appendChild(comm);
}else {
    clear();
}

    };
</script>
```

the id "info" is a div

this is basically a vertical navigation bar that shows tooltips in a div under the buttons when you hover over them.

So I want to first check if the div has no value then if it doesn't then it will append text into it, else it will clear the text but i also want it to append the text after it clears. I'm not sure how to do this and help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: a DIV has no value, try innerHTML instead.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish with `if (where.style.value)`?  The `style` object has no property named `value`.  `where.innerHTML = ""` will work just fine for clearing a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to clear the item anyways and put your new text in, why even bothering with the conditional? You could just as easily do:

```
function dostuff(what) {
    where.innerHTML = what;
};
```

<kbd>[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/gehowide/1/edit)</kbd>